# How to fix error "White label error page" when connecting to jsp file

Tags: html, spring-boot, jsp

Im trying to create a simple webapp with spring boot and im currently getting an error i cannot get past.

The error shows "Whitelabel Error Page the application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback

There was an unxpected error (type= Not Found, status = 404).
/index.jsp"

This is my current code with along side the jsp files.

this is my java file:

```
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

 @Controller
 public class UserController {

       @RequestMapping("/")
       public String register(){
             return "Login.jsp";
       }
 }
```

and this is my jsp file:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language = "java" %>

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="login-box">
      <h1> Login </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="textbox">
      <input type="text" placeholder = "username" name="" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="textbox">
      <input type="text" placeholder = "password" name="" value="">
    </div>

    <input class="btn" type = "button" name = "" value="">

  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried many solutions such as; adding the right dependencies, changing of the folders as well as changing around file names.

What would be the main reason i am receiving this error?

thanks.

Comment: Have you kept your jsp file in template folder?

Answer (score 0):

Move your .jsp files in templates folder which is under resource package. and add the following lines in your `application.properties` file

```
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```